# Use pysftp without compression or at a specified compression level

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to connect to a server using `pysftp` to transfer files.
Whenever I run

```
con = pysftp.Connection('ftp.abc.com', username='user', password='my_pass')
```

I get the `SSHException` saying incompatible ssh server, which is most probably due to the compression used (or not used).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysftp.py", line 162, in __init__
    self._transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 978, in connect
    self.start_client()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 406, in start_client
    raise e
SSHException: Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable compression) [] [] ('none',)
```

It is not a problem with the server itself because when I run `sftp -v ftp.abc.com`, I get the following output:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
...
debug1: Connection established.
...
...
...
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version JSCAPE
debug1: no match: JSCAPE
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client 3des-cbc hmac-md5 zlib
debug1: kex: client->server 3des-cbc hmac-md5 zlib
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ...
debug1: Host ... is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/.../.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

And it works fine after entering the password.

I did some reading and tried sftping into the server without compression, but I was unable to. It'd always enable compression even after I changed the `ssh_config` file and specified `-oCompression=no` at the commandline.

So, how do I connect without using compression, and more importantly, is there a way to use pysftp with compression level set to 6?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I sorted out the paramiko part.

I downloaded the [source code](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) and then I had to change the `_preferred_compression` to `zlib`. It is set to `none` by default.

In line number 102 in paramiko/transport.py, I changed the line

```
_preferred_compression = ('none',)
```

to

```
_preferred_compression = ('zlib',)
```

It worked, but I have no idea why paramiko is unable to negotiate to it.

And the part about running `sftp` without compression still remains answered.
Any help will be appreciated.